# Why does my python method print out 'None' when I try to print out the string that the method returns?

Tags: python

This is the problem I'm running into, instead of returning new_word and printing it out it just prints 'None'

```
    text = "hey hey hey,hey"
    word = 'hey'

    def censor(text,word):
        new_word = ""
        count = 0
        if word in text:
            latter_count = ((text.index(word))+len(word))
            while count < text.index(word):
                new_word+= text[count]
                count += 1
            for i in range(len(word)):
                new_word += '*'
            while latter_count < len(text) :
                new_word += text[latter_count]
                latter_count += 1

            if word in new_word :
                censor(new_word,word)
            else :
                return new_word
    print censor(text,word)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function returns `None` if there is no return statement.

Probably while doing recursion, `if word in text:` is False, and so there is nothing to return. You also did not return the recursive step. You must *return* `censor(new_word,word)`

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning in the first branch of the `if` toward the end.  Change that to

```
if word in new_word:
    return censor(new_word,word)
```

Your function will also return None if `word in text` is false, so you might want to add an `else` at the end to return an empty string or some other default value in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If the function hits the end without hitting a "return" statement, it's the same as "return None":

```
def censor(text,word):
    new_word = ""
    count = 0
    if word in text:
        latter_count = ((text.index(word))+len(word))
        while count < text.index(word):
            new_word+= text[count]
            count += 1
        for i in range(len(word)):
            new_word += '*'
        while latter_count < len(text) :
            new_word += text[latter_count]
            latter_count += 1

        if word in new_word :
            censor(new_word,word)  # probably want to return here
        else :                     # don't need this else if you return in the if branch
            return new_word

    # what do you want to return in this case?
    return None
```